# Shuffle a list of integers with Java 8 Streams API

Tags: java, scala, java-stream

I tried to translate the following line of Scala to Java 8 using the Streams API:

```
// Scala
util.Random.shuffle((1 to 24).toList)
```

To write the equivalent in Java I created a range of integers:

```
IntStream.range(1, 25)
```

I suspected to find a `toList` method in the stream API, but `IntStream` only knows the strange method:

```
collect(
  Supplier<R> supplier, ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

How can I shuffle a list with Java 8 Streams API?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here you go:

```
List<Integer> integers =
    IntStream.range(1, 10)                      // <-- creates a stream of ints
        .boxed()                                // <-- converts them to Integers
        .collect(Collectors.toList());          // <-- collects the values to a list

Collections.shuffle(integers);

System.out.println(integers);
```

Prints:

```
[8, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 9, 7]
```

Comment: In practice, it'd be better to map using Integer::valueOf() in order to take advantage of the Integer cache, even if it hardly matters for such a small range.

Comment: I edited the answer to use `IntStream.boxed()`, which is pretty much canonical.

Comment: I hadn't seen this answer when I posted mine, and didn't know about `boxed()`; this is better than what I had, although I think you can statically import `Collectors.toList` and can let the compiler infer the type of the list.

Comment: Thank you very much. The beauty of Scala is just so obvious to me.

Comment: Yeah, I am still surprised by the verbosity of Java 8. Chances are this would be resolved in libraries like Guava.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev - I'm surprised that people are surprised!  1) The verbosity of Java 8 is a consequence of the need to maintain source code compatibility with earlier versions of the Java language.  2) This is not something a 3rd party library could "fix". 3) If this is a serious problem for you, consider using a different JVM-based language.  (And an interesting new contender just went "1.0" ...)

Comment: @StephenC Many thanks for a tip - haven't thought of Dart as a JVM language and will definitely try it when it gets better JVM/IDE support. As for example, I might be wrong, but this would be more concise and efficient if collectors/consumers for primitives had been introduced. That's what I'm expecting to see in i.e. Trove collections...

Comment: @AndreyChaschev I think StephenC meant Ceylon, not Dart. However I think Scala is the better language. Maybe Kotlin has a good chance because of the good IDE support from JetBrains.

Comment: @deamon I have been expecting Kotlin to shoot, but now I have doubts it will survive Dart and Scala.

Comment: Ugh.  It is not really a streams solution.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work as written per [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), since `toList()` doesn't guarantee the mutability of the `List` returned.  This works in practice since the current implementation of `toList()` happens to return an `ArrayList`, which is mutable.  To ensure continued correctness if the implementation changes, we'd could explicitly declare the collection type (`Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`), or copy the results of `toList` into a mutable list (`new ArrayList<>(integers)`).

Comment: @M.Justin or just switch to Kotlin/Scala to avoid lengthy talks

Answer (score 51):

You may find the following `toShuffledList()` method useful.

```
private static final Collector<?, ?, ?> SHUFFLER = Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new),
        list -> {
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            return list;
        }
);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toShuffledList() {
    return (Collector<T, ?, List<T>>) SHUFFLER;
}
```

This enables the following kind of one-liner:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
         .mapToObj(a -> (char) a)
         .collect(toShuffledList())
         .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Example output:

```
AVBFYXIMUDENOTHCRJKWGQZSPL
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work as written per [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), since `toList()` doesn't guarantee the mutability of the `List` returned.  This works in practice since the current implementation of `toList()` happens to return an `ArrayList`, which is mutable.  To ensure continued correctness if the implementation changes, we'd could explicitly declare the collection type (`Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`), or copy the results of `toList` into a mutable list (`new ArrayList<>(integers)`).

Comment: @M.Justin Thanks, I've edited the answer. This is one of the most infuriating things about the Stream API. It doesn't guarantee mutability or thread safety of the returned List, or even whether it has an O(1) `get` method. Along with so much of the Stream API, this is just terrible. Taking the argument to its logical conclusion, the only methods on the returned lists you should ever actually use are `size` and `iterator`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Taking it even further, it's worth noting that some specialty collection implementations don't even have a O(1) `size` operation (though those are definitely outliers) — https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#size--

Answer (score 17):

You can use a custom comparator that "sorts" the values by a random value:

```
public final class RandomComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final Map<T, Integer> map = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    private final Random random;

    public RandomComparator() {
        this(new Random());
    }

    public RandomComparator(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        return Integer.compare(valueFor(t1), valueFor(t2));
    }

    private int valueFor(T t) {
        synchronized (map) {
            return map.computeIfAbsent(t, ignore -> random.nextInt());
        }
    }

}
```

Each object in the stream is (lazily) associated a random integer value, on which we sort. The synchronization on the map is to deal with parallel streams.

You can then use it like that:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 24).boxed()
    .sorted(new RandomComparator<>())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The advantage of this solution is that it integrates within the stream pipeline.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29251881/1553851) for a nice alternative.

Comment: this answer doesn't work well anymore due to a change in the sort algorithm: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6804124 that can complain when the comparator doesn't respect a basic contract.

Comment: The change in sort algorithm happened in 2009, so nothing new here. Do you have examples where this breaks?
The only issue I see is inconsistency with equals in case of (unlikely) collisions in random.nextInt(), and even that shouldn't prevent the shuffling to happen.

Comment: @user1928596 What contract is the comparator breaking? Since it's storing a mapping of each value and comparing those, it meets all the criteria described in the requirements of `Comparator.compareTo`.

Comment: This will not fully shuffle if there are duplicate elements in the list, as they will always end up adjacent to each other.  For instance, the list `[1,5,1,1,5]` will become either `[5,5,1,1,1]` or `[1,1,1,5,5]`.

Comment: @user1928596 Except it doesn't violate that.  It's storing a (random) mapping of `T` => `Integer`, and comparing on that integer.  Since the mapping doesn't change during the life of the comparator, `f(A)<f(B) and f(B)<f(C) => f(A)<f(C)`, where `f(x)` is the mapping function.  This solution is equivalent to `Comparator.comparing(t -> { synchronized (map) { return map.computeIfAbsent(t, ignore -> random.nextInt()); }});`, which perhaps more clearly illustrates how this meets the basic contract.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to process the whole Stream without too much hassle, you can simply create your own Collector using `Collectors.collectingAndThen()`:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Stream<T>> toEagerShuffledStream() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
      toList(),
      list -> {
          Collections.shuffle(list);
          return list.stream();
      });
}
```

But this won't perform well if you want to `limit()` the resulting Stream. In order to overcome this, one could create a custom Spliterator:

```
package com.pivovarit.stream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.RandomAccess;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

class ImprovedRandomSpliterator<T, LIST extends RandomAccess & List<T>> implements Spliterator<T> {

    private final Random random;
    private final List<T> source;
    private int size;

    ImprovedRandomSpliterator(LIST source, Supplier<? extends Random> random) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(source, "source can't be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(random, "random can't be null");

        this.source = source;
        this.random = random.get();
        this.size = this.source.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (size > 0) {
            int nextIdx = random.nextInt(size);
            int lastIdx = --size;

            T last = source.get(lastIdx);
            T elem = source.set(nextIdx, last);
            action.accept(elem);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return source.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return SIZED;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public final class RandomCollectors {

    private RandomCollectors() {
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Stream<T>> toImprovedLazyShuffledStream() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
          toCollection(ArrayList::new),
          list -> !list.isEmpty()
            ? StreamSupport.stream(new ImprovedRandomSpliterator<>(list, Random::new), false)
            : Stream.empty());
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Stream<T>> toEagerShuffledStream() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
          toCollection(ArrayList::new),
          list -> {
              Collections.shuffle(list);
              return list.stream();
          });
    }
}
```

I explained the performance considerations here: https://4comprehension.com/implementing-a-randomized-stream-spliterator-in-java/

Answer (score 3):

To perform a shuffle efficiently you need all the values in advance.  You can use Collections.shuffle() after you have converted the stream to a list like you do in Scala.

Comment: And how can I transform the `IntStream` to a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: @deamon See Andrey's answer.  Of course it would be simpler and faster if you just use a loop to build the array.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just playing with Java 8, so performance is not so important at the moment.

Comment: @deamon Java is still not as functional as Scala :|

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a "streaming only" solution and a deterministic, merely "haphazard" ordering versus a "random" ordering is Good Enough, you can always sort your `int`s by a hash value:

```
List<Integer> xs=IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .boxed()
    .sorted( (a, b) -> a.hashCode() - b.hashCode() )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you'd rather have an `int[]` than a `List<Integer>`, you can just unbox them afterwards. Unfortunately, you have go through the boxing step to apply a custom `Comparator`, so there's no eliminating that part of the process.

```
List<Integer> ys=IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .boxed()
    .sorted( (a, b) -> a.hashCode() - b.hashCode() )
    .mapToInt( a -> a.intValue())
    .toArray();
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The problem is that `Integer::hashCode` returns the same thing as `Integer::intValue`.  (It is in the javadoc!)  And even if you use `System::identityHashCode`, it is going to be system dependent how random the shuffle is, for a couple of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> randomShuffledRange(int startInclusive, int endExclusive) {
    return new Random().ints(startInclusive, endExclusive)
            .distinct()
            .limit(endExclusive-startInclusive)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

var shuffled = randomShuffledRange(1, 10);
System.out.println(shuffled);
```

Example output:

```
[4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my one line solution:
I am picking one random color:

```
colourRepository.findAll().stream().sorted((o1,o2)-> RandomUtils.nextInt(-1,1)).findFirst().get()
```

Comment: This `Comparator` violates the general contract for `Comparator`.  Comparing the same two values isn't consistent, and comparing `x` with `y` and `y` with `x` will not necessarily return opposite results.  With the right input and random seed, I was able to get sorting this way to throw an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`. On my version of Java, one specific example is: `Random r = new Random(9); Collections.nCopies(32, 1).stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> r.nextInt(3) - 1).findFirst().get()`