# Excluding numbers from interval, retrieving the rest

Tags: java, list, random

I want an interval of numbers between 0 and 9 using random generator. For example, if I already received 0,2,7 i don't want those numbers again, instead i want one of the rest between the given interval[1 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 8 or 9].

Comment: This isn't random. You want to take the numbers `[1,9]` in a `Collection` and shuffle it. The pull from the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Boris the Spider says:

```
// We want numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive
int min = 0, max = 9; 
// We need a Collection, lets use a List, could use any ordered collection here
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
// Put the numbers in the collection
for (int n=min; n<=max; n++) { nums.add(n); }

// Randomly sort (shuffle) the collection
Collections.shuffle(nums);

// Pull numbers from the collection (the order should be random now)
for (int count=0; count<nums.length; count++) {
    System.out.println("Number " + count + " is " + nums.get(count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution runs in better time performance with math.random.

```
LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2); //or more

while (!numbers.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(numbers.remove((int) (Math.random() * numbers.size())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With java 8 you can do the following

```
List<Integer> integers = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(integers);
```

As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058488/1809463).

Answer (score -1):

This is an alternative approach to `Java.util.Collections`, which uses the `Java.util.Random` class.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{

    final static int RAND_CAP = 9;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        while (usedNumbers.size() < RAND_CAP) {
            int randNum = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % RAND_CAP) + 1;
            if (!usedNumbers.contains(randNum)) {
                usedNumbers.add(randNum);
                System.out.println(randNum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[run code here](http://ideone.com/IarN81)

Comment: This is very poor as performance degrades as you reach the end of the required numbers. In fact, there is no reason the second number should ever return - `random.nextInt` can keep returning the same number. Further `List.contains` is `O(n)`, `Set.contains` is `O(1)`. This answer shows a fundamental misunderstanding of both programmatic randomness and the Java collections API.