# Is it possible to shuffle a stream in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

or put it in another way, perform stream.forEach() in random order. (without using calling .collect() first)

Comment: “without calling collect”… you could use `sorted(…)` with a [shuffling comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29251881/2711488)

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of the other question?  The other question is about generating a randomized range of integers; this one seems more general - how to create a shuffled stream.