# Compact shuffling code in Java

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

I need to generate an array of integers in random order repeatedly in Java. I came up with the following ugly snippet (which runs in a bigger loop). What's a more efficient or compact way to do the same?

```
    ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] d = new int[elts];
    for (int i = 0; i < elts; i++) {
        t.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < elts; i++) {
        d[i] = t.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058366/shuffle-a-list-of-integers-with-java-8-streams-api

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Java 8 Stream API:

```
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, elts).boxed().collect(toList());
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    int[] d = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

The same with Java 8 Stream API but using `collectAndThen()`

```
IntStream.range(0, elts).  // range from 0 to elts
      boxed().  // from int to Integer
      collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), integers -> { //collect to list  
          Collections.shuffle(integers);  //shuffle integer
          return integers.toArray(new Integer[integers.size()]); // convert list to array
      }));
```

and with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
    int[] ints = IntStreamEx.range(0, elts)
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> random.nextInt())
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Will work well in Java 8

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.range(0, elts).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(range);
Integer[] arr = new Integer[elts];
range.toArray(arr);
```

Comment: Duplicate, the last two line can be merged, the question has int[] and not Integer[], and use zero sized arrays with toArray (https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/).