# Random permutation of IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream

Every now and then I find myself with indexed loops, for which I want to permutate the order to some random order.
I usually transition from something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    // do stuff with i
}
```

to

```
List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, max)
    .boxed()
    toCollection(() -> new ArrayList(max)));
Collections.shuffle(indices);
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    int index = indices.get(i);
    // do stuff with index
}
```

This is neither efficient nor elegant. Is it possible to create a `Stream` (ideally an `IntStream`) in a certain range, but have it return its elements shuffled? I am thinking of something along the lines of:

```
IntStream.range(0, max)
        .shuffled() // this method doesn't exist
        .forEach(IntConsumer::accept);
```

The resulting `IntStream` should still include all elements in the range `[0, max)` exactly **once**.

---

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058366/shuffle-a-list-of-integers-with-java-8-streams-api), because I don't want to create a `List` and shuffle it. This solution has a massive overhead since it is working with `Integer`s, while also redundantly creating and shuffling a `List`. I have provided that solution in my own example, so I am fully aware of that approach.

Comment: @NicholasK I don't want a `List` and shuffle it. I have provided that solution myself. I am asking for a solution which creates a shuffled `IntStream` in an elegant way

Comment: Folks, this is not a dup. The poster is saying that he finds the solution to the other question "neither efficient nor elegant" and is looking for a better way.

Comment: Did you look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36391959/1746118) as from the linked question as well?

Comment: @nullpointer thanks for trying to find a solution, but yes, I have. Neither do I want to use an intermediary `List`, nor do I want to box my `int`s.

Comment: Why are you using `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`? Both operations, `shuffle` and iterating via index calling `get`, are horribly inefficient with this list type. In fact, most operations are.

Comment: @Holger you are right. I coded this example in the Stackoverflow editor and didn't pay much attention to efficiency. It only served the purpose of showing what kind of solutions I am not looking for (meaning examples which collect to `List`s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? It's pretty much the same thing you have, except it encapsulates all the nitty gritty and just gives you a pure `IntStream`. Also it doesn't have to do so much boxing and unboxing.

```
public class ShuffledIntStream {

    public static IntStream to(int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] values = new int[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            values[i] = i;
        }
        for (int i = max; i > 1; i--) {
            swap(values, i - 1, r.nextInt(max));
        }
        return IntStream.of(values);
    }

    private static void swap(int[] values, int i, int j) {
        int temp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[j];
        values[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a built in solution. But this solution is fast and it does what I asked for. Thanks!

Comment: You can create the initial array using `int[] values = IntStream.range(0, max).toArray();`. Further, I’d use `Arrays.stream(values)` instead of the *varargs* method `IntStream.of(values)`. And for performance reasons, it’s recommended to replace `Random r = new Random();` with `ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Random.ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-):

```
new Random().ints(0, max)
    .distinct()
    .limit(max)
    .forEach(IntConsumer::accept);
```

`ints` will produce a stream of ints between `0` and `max`, [`distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct--) makes sure that there are no duplicates, and [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) to get exactly how many you want.

Comment: Maybe I have not made myself sufficiently clear, but I want all number in the 0-max range to occur exactly once. Like in a loop

Comment: Isn't that what the call to distinct does?

Comment: Ok, with that recent edit it looks like this does what I was asking for. Does this execute with performance `O(n)` or is the runtime indeterministic?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn the original version of the answer didn't include that part. And edits done immediately after creating a post are not shown. So you'll have to trust me on that ;)

Comment: It could repeatedly generate duplicate values that have to be filtered out by `distinct` so not exactly O(n). The first number will always be unique. For the i-th there is a `i/max` chance it will be a dup. So on the last number you'll probably have to generate another `max` values before happening across the one that's still unused. For `max = 10` that's probably okay, might be a bigger issue for larger values of `max`.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn that's that what I thought. I will wait another day, if no answer comes along that provides a solution with O(n) runtime, I will accept yours. Thanks